# How declare extern struct?

Tags: c, function, struct, typedef

I can using struct in now defining struct but how declare function or struct dependencing tohether?

**test.h**

```
extern struct foo;
typedef int (*test)(FOO *f);
typedef struct foo
{
char a;
test *t;
} FOO;

int haha(FOO *f) { return 0;}

typedef struct foo
{
char a;
test *t;
} FOO;
```

**test.c**

```
int main() {FOO e; return 0; }
```

Comment: As well as the pointer issue, you specifically asked about `extern`. What do you mean by an extern struct - what are you hoping to achieve? This compile unit will need the full definition if it ever needs to use the contents of the struct. Did you mean an extern instance of the struct?

Comment: in my struct i need pointer to function or struct foo. function or struct foo have parameter or member prev struct. the trouble is how declaring struct dependence together. Not variable.

Comment: OK, so I think the answer below is what you want then: you need do declare the members as pointers-to-structs rather than embedded structs. The function pointer should just work OK.

Comment: If you're trying to store a pointer to the struct in the struct (e.g. a linked list) then put a `struct foo *` into the structure; which is valid. You can't just put a `struct foo` in there if you don't know the size by that point.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can not define a structure variable (or member inside another structure) unless you have the full definition of the actual structure. Forward declarations are not full definitions. If you have a forward declaration all you can declare is a pointer to the structure.

That means all you can do is something like

```
typedef struct bar BAR;  // Forward declaration of the structure and type-alias definition in one line
typedef struct foo FOO;  // Forward declaration of the structure and type-alias definition in one line

struct foo {
    char a;
    BAR *b;  // Define a *pointer* to the BAR structure
    FOO *s;  // Define a *pointer* to the FOO structure
};
```

This works because to declare a pointer to a structure, the compiler only has to know that the structure exists, it doesn't need the full structure definition. For this a normal forward declaration is all you need.

Also note that when referencing a structure recursively a pointer is needed too, because the full definition is not complete until the closing brace.

Comment: You noc compiling this code because struct **bar** is depending **foo**

Comment: @MarkoLustro This will work fine. Defining a *pointer* only needs the forward declaration as shown.

Comment: @MarkoLustro You'll also want to make the `struct foo` inside `struct bar` a pointer too I think - but even if you didn't, the existing definition ought to compile with the replacement foo definition above since it knows the size of foo at that point.